# MySQL - number column desc index, show Nulls last

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.6 and i want to create an index on a number (`tinyint`) column, which can have `null` values.

If i do it now, the default `ORDER BY` is `ASC` and i imagine that's why the `null` values in my columns are returned first, but i want them to be returned last.

I've seen that for returning `null` values last, you can run a query like:

`SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY -columnname DESC`

Is there an "equivalent" of that for indexing in MySQL 5.6?
Would there be an extra cost associated with it?

Comment: AFAIK an index on that column should already be usable.  Run `EXPLAIN` to verify.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand.. what index should already be available?

Comment: *the null values in my columns are returned first, but i want them to be returned last.* What ORDER BY expression do you use? if none - this is "by design" and cannot be altered.

Comment: 1) `CREATE INDEX idx ON tablename (columnname)`, 2) Run `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no index was used when running this query.

Comment: @Akina i didn't use one when creating the index, but can't i create one?

Comment: ORDER BY is a clause in SELECT query which retrieves the data in the order which you need, not in index. If it is absent then the rows order has every right to be any.

Comment: @Akina right, but can't i create an index that will return the rows in `DESC` order? (without using the `ORDER BY` clause in my `SELECT` statement`)

Comment: If your MySQL version is 8+ you may (with some restrictions - read CREATE INDEX article). In 5+ ASC/DESC are parsed but ignored.